# Java: Passing arguments at readObject/writeObject methods

Tags: java, serialization

I override the methods `readObject/writeObject` in order to customize the serialization of my objects. The problem is that these methods take no arguments. Is there anyway to pass parameters in these methods so I can use them in my serialization process?

Thank you in advance

Comment: And how would these arguments be passed exactly? When calling `objectOutputStream.writeObject(foo)`, no argument can be given. The question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: These methods are for serializing the state of the object which should be accessible to them. Why you want to pass the args? If some info is required to customize the serialization than it should be part of state of object

Comment: What kind of parameters were you expecting? Serializing of an Object just needs the object. If you want custom serialization, you need to implement it differently.

Comment: The problem is that these methods *do* take arguments: a stream object. What's your actual question?

Comment: I have a similar requirement. The reason it is required is to initialise transient fields which depend on the current environment state at the time the object is restored and are not permanenet properties of the object. The solution, as suggested by pablo is the right idea: subclass ObjectInputStream and pass the parameters in your subclass. The readObject method of the object class can then access the parameters and initialise the transient fields

Answer (score 0):

No there is no option to pass parameters, moreover why would you need to do that.

Serialization, De serialization is the process of writing and reading an object state, so your class should have all the properties within it before being serialized or deserialized.

There shouldn't be any reason to pass parameters to these two methods.

Comment: Well I agree that in most cases it does not make any sense but let me explain you my scenario. I have a class Record which contains Fields. Each field writes/reads its payload based on an encoding that is attribute of the Record. Do you suggest a different workaround for this?

Comment: If Field depends on the encoding then encoding should be part of Field, by doing so you get rid of this issue altogether

Comment: If this encoding is the same for every field of the record, adding the attribute encoding on each field will be redundancy. I want a workaround that can handle those cases efficiently

Comment: Since Field is dependent on Record Encoding, either Field should have encoding as an attribute or else Field should have a reference of Encoding, which makes better OOP

Comment: Actually Field had a reference on the Record but I thought it was mixing up things and I decided to cut it off. The point in a more general way is that I want a reference on the caller (since I write Record object and Record object has references on Fields I want to know what Record did actually triggered the write operation of the Field object)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the signature of the read/write methods. One way of going around it is set and store your serialisation parameters in your objects and use them in the read/write methods.

Or you could make a static class, sth like SerializationParameter, and store your serialisation parameters there. Since they would be static you would not have to duplicate them in memory for each serialised object.